# Pandas parsing text files with different signs for change line and separator

Tags: python, pandas, parsing

I am parsing a txt file which use '#@#@#' for change line and '~' for column separation. Can I still use pd.read_csv() to parse it to get a DataFrame?

Comment: Look at the specs, there is a lineterminator option and a delimiter option: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: length of lineterminator has to be 1, so is possible use `df = pd.read_csv(filename, lineterminator='#', sep='~')` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is main problem length of lineterminator has to be `1`, so is possible use filtering after [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
temp=u"""a~h~h#@#@#a~h~h#@#@#"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), lineterminator='#', sep='~', header=None)
print (df)
   0    1    2
0  a    h    h
1  @  NaN  NaN
2  @  NaN  NaN
3  a    h    h
4  @  NaN  NaN
5  @  NaN  NaN

df = df[df.iloc[:,0] != '@']
print (df)
   0  1  2
0  a  h  h
3  a  h  h
```